# Why do df and df -h show different value? How does df -h perform calculation?

Tags: disk-usage, coreutils

how exactly df -h works? If I run `df`, I get this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      41943040 7659828  34283212  19% /
```

If I run `df -h`, I get this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       40G  7.4G   33G  19% /
```

The question is how to get same numbers?

41943040 / 1024 / 1024 = 40 OK, let's divide others by 1024.

```
7659828 / 1024 / 1024 = 7,304981
```

Then maybe by 1000?

```
7659828 / 1000 / 1000 = 7,659828
```

How `df -h` got 7.4G?

```
34283212 / 1024 / 1024 = 32,695, which is ±33G
```

While df is open source, I've [cloned](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) the repo and checked the code. That's what I found:

```
for (col = 0; col < ncolumns; col++)
    {
      char *cell = NULL;
      char const *header = _(columns[col]->caption);

      if (columns[col]->field == SIZE_FIELD
          && (header_mode == DEFAULT_MODE
              || (header_mode == OUTPUT_MODE
                  && !(human_output_opts & human_autoscale))))
        {
          char buf[LONGEST_HUMAN_READABLE + 1];

          int opts = (human_suppress_point_zero
                      | human_autoscale | human_SI
                      | (human_output_opts
                         & (human_group_digits | human_base_1024 | human_B)));

          /* Prefer the base that makes the human-readable value more exact,
             if there is a difference.  */

          uintmax_t q1000 = output_block_size;
          uintmax_t q1024 = output_block_size;
          bool divisible_by_1000;
          bool divisible_by_1024;

          do
            {
              divisible_by_1000 = q1000 % 1000 == 0;  q1000 /= 1000;
              divisible_by_1024 = q1024 % 1024 == 0;  q1024 /= 1024;
            }
          while (divisible_by_1000 & divisible_by_1024);

          if (divisible_by_1000 < divisible_by_1024)
            opts |= human_base_1024;
          if (divisible_by_1024 < divisible_by_1000)
            opts &= ~human_base_1024;
          if (! (opts & human_base_1024))
            opts |= human_B;

          char *num = human_readable (output_block_size, buf, opts, 1, 1);

          /* Reset the header back to the default in OUTPUT_MODE.  */
          header = _("blocks");

          /* TRANSLATORS: this is the "1K-blocks" header in "df" output.  */
          if (asprintf (&cell, _("%s-%s"), num, header) == -1)
            cell = NULL;
        }
      else if (header_mode == POSIX_MODE && columns[col]->field == SIZE_FIELD)
        {
          char buf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (uintmax_t)];
          char *num = umaxtostr (output_block_size, buf);

          /* TRANSLATORS: this is the "1024-blocks" header in "df -P".  */
          if (asprintf (&cell, _("%s-%s"), num, header) == -1)
            cell = NULL;
        }
      else
        cell = strdup (header);

      if (!cell)
        xalloc_die ();

      hide_problematic_chars (cell);

      table[nrows - 1][col] = cell;

      columns[col]->width = MAX (columns[col]->width, mbswidth (cell, 0));
    }
```

I don't have experience with this language but as I understand, it tries to check if the value on each column is dividable by 1024 or 1000 and choose whatever is better to render values for the `-h` option. But I don't get the same value no matter whether I divide by 1000 or 1024. Why?

I think I know why. It checks to divide by 1000 or 1024 on *each* division.

```
          if (divisible_by_1000 < divisible_by_1024)
            opts |= human_base_1024;
          if (divisible_by_1024 < divisible_by_1000)
            opts &= ~human_base_1024;
          if (! (opts & human_base_1024))
            opts |= human_B;
```

so let's crack 7659828 / 1024 / 1024 = 7,304981. `-h` gave answer of **7.4G**

```
7659828 / 1024 = 7480,xxx
7659828 / 1000 = 7659,xxx
```

while 7659 is more than 7480, divide by 1024.

Still a big number, let's continue:

```
7659828 / 1024 / 1024 = 7,xxx  (7,3049..)
7659828 / 1024 / 1000 = 7,xxx  (7,4803..)
```

it takes 1000 now and gives 7,48 and I **believe** somewhere in the code it rounds down so "better say less than more" while you can put in 7.4G of data but you can't put 7.5G.

Same story with 33.4G

```
34283212 / 1024 / 1000 = 33.47...
```

So it becomes 33G.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you posted is from the function "get_header" which generates the text in the first row.
In your case this applies to the heading "1K-blocks" (call `df  -B1023` to see the difference).

Important to note: "1K" refers to 1024-byte blocks, not to 1000-byte blocks (indicated by "1kB-blocks", see `df -B1000`)

The calculation of the numbers in the human readable format is handled by function "human_readable" (human.c:153).
In df.c:1571 you can find the options which are used when called with the `-h` flag:

```
case 'h':
    human_output_opts = human_autoscale | human_SI | human_base_1024;
    output_block_size = 1;
    break;
```

All calculations are done with base 1024 in human readable format ("-h").
In addition to the shown human_output_opts, there is a default setting which applies here (see human.h, enum declaration):

```
/* The following three options are mutually exclusive.  */
/* Round to plus infinity (default).  */
human_ceiling = 0,
/* Round to nearest, ties to even.  */
human_round_to_nearest = 1,
/* Round to minus infinity.  */
human_floor = 2,
```

As human_output_opts does not include human_round_to_nearest or human_floor, it will use its default value of human_ceiling. All calculated values will therefore be rounded up.

To verify the settings, we can try to calculate the human readable format based on the 1K-blocks from `df`:

```
Size = ceil(41943040/1024/1024) = ceil(40) = 40
Used = ceil(7659828/1024/1024) = ceil(7.305) = 7.4
Available = ceil(34283212/1024/1024) = ceil(32.695) = 33
```

Which is the same as the output of `df -h`.

(... and if you prefer 1000-byte format, you can simply call `df -H`).

Comment: Yeah, this is the right answer. This has been asked before... Anyone reading the `info` page for `df` will learn that _"Normally the disk space is printed in units of 1024 bytes, but this
can be overridden (note Block size). **Non-integer quantities are
rounded up to the next higher unit.**"_ (emphasize mine)

Comment: I've deleted my answer while it was incorrect but added thoughts to question for reference :) Thanks for the input @M2C8

Comment: `ceil(7.3) == 8`, right? I would think that if they want a ceiling with a 1 decimal digit precision, they need to x10 and /10 along the way (`ceil(x * 10.0) / 10.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `df` program from FreeBSD (this is where `df -h` is originally from) nor the `df` implementation from Solaris behave this way.

Since the Solaris sources are OpenSource, you may check whether you could compile `df` on your OS: